# Problem setting up OpenGL dev environment in Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: opengl, linux

Currently I'm using [this](https://open.gl/context) tutorial to get started with opengl.So when I try to compile the example program :

```
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>
#include <thread>

int main()
{
    glfwInit();
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(1));
    glfwTerminate();
}
```

using

> g++ test.cpp -o test  -lglfw3

to ensure that all is good with glfw I get this

> In file included from /usr/include/c++/4.8/thread:35:0,
>                    from test.cpp:2: /usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/c++0x_warning.h:32:2: error: #error This
>   file requires compiler and library support for the ISO C++ 2011
>   standard. This support is currently experimental, and must be enabled
>   with the -std=c++11 or -std=gnu++11 compiler options.  #error This
>   file requires compiler and library support for the \   ^ test.cpp: In
>   function ‘int main()’: test.cpp:7:10: error: ‘std::this_thread’ has
>   not been declared
>        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(1));
>             ^ test.cpp:7:38: error: ‘std::chrono’ has not been declared
>        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(1));

So then I guessed I could use the flag that g++ suggested and compile it using

> g++ -std=c++11 test.cpp -o test  -lglfw3

But then things get weirder and g++ comes with this error(I will post only a part of it since it's a huge output overall but you will probably get the idea) :

> x11_window.c:(.text+0x2d9): undefined reference to `XSaveContext'
>   x11_window.c:(.text+0x324): undefined reference to`
>   XChangeWindowAttributes' x11_window.c:(.text+0x3be): undefined
>   reference to `XSetWMProtocols' x11_window.c:(.text+0x417): undefined
>   reference to`XChangeProperty' x11_window.c:(.text+0x41c): undefined
>   reference to `XAllocWMHints' x11_window.c:(.text+0x48e): undefined
>   reference to`XSetWMHints' x11_window.c:(.text+0x49d): undefined
>   reference to `XFree' x11_window.c:(.text+0x4a2): undefined reference
>   to`XAllocSizeHints' x11_window.c:(.text+0x5ed): undefined reference
>   to `XSetWMNormalHints' x11_window.c:(.text+0x5fc): undefined reference
>   to`XFree' x11_window.c:(.text+0x613): undefined reference to
>   `XAllocClassHint' x11_window.c:(.text+0x66c): undefined reference to`
>   XSetClassHint' x11_window.c:(.text+0x67b): undefined reference to
>   `XFree' x11_window.c:(.text+0x6dc): undefined reference to`
>   XISelectEvents' x11_window.c:(.text+0x71e): undefined reference to
>   `XRRSelectInput' //usr/local/lib/libglfw3.a(x11_window.c.o): In
>   function`hideCursor': x11_window.c:(.text+0x7bd): undefined reference
>   to `XUngrabPointer' x11_window.c:(.text+0x7fb): undefined reference to`
>   XDefineCursor' //usr/local/lib/libglfw3.a(x11_window.c.o): In
>   function `captureCursor': x11_window.c:(.text+0x880): undefined
>   reference to`XGrabPointer'
>   //usr/local/lib/libglfw3.a(x11_window.c.o): In function `showCursor':

How could I fix this type of problem cause it really hurts my motivation to get into opengl. And please if you have in mind any better-hassle free guide for setting a proper opengl environment for deving with glfw and glew in linux/ubuntu , care to mention it.

UPDATE 1: http://pastebin.com/CPEwmbUZ <--- The whole output is here if anyone cares.

Answer (score 1):

Error `undefined reference` means that linker can't find function's definition. Probably, you should link X11 library to your program by console parameter `-lX11`. So, it should be `g++ -std=c++11 test.cpp -o test -lglfw3 -lX11`. I think you should link OpenGL library too (by `-lGL`).

Comment: Well I used this command : `g++ -std=c++11 test.cpp -o test -lglfw3 -lX11 -lGL` and I'm getting this, shorter , error : `/usr/bin/ld: //usr/local/lib/libglfw3.a(x11_init.c.o): undefined reference to symbol 'XF86VidModeQueryExtension'
//usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXxf86vm.so.1: error adding symbols: DSO missing from command line
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status`

Comment: try to add `-lXxf86vm -L/user/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/` to command. This should fix errors.

Comment: `g++ -std=c++11 test.cpp -o test -lglfw3 -lX11 -lGL -lXxf86vm -L/user/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/` Gives this error : `/usr/bin/ld: //usr/local/lib/libglfw3.a(glx_context.c.o): undefined reference to symbol 'pthread_key_delete@@GLIBC_2.2.5'
//lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0: error adding symbols: DSO missing from command line
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status` I feel so stupid wasting your time but really why is it so complicated for such a small program. Well I hope I will manage it once I find the right commands.

Comment: Add `-lpthread`. If you have `undefined reference to symbol` compilation error of function from some other library (not your function), that often means, that you forgot to add library. You can find in "google" what library you should add by request "undefined reference to symbol 'pthread_key_delete'". That's not always clear to understand what library you need, but it's works. In your case, you need this library because you use `#include <thread>`.

Comment: About `-std=c++11`. C++ language has different versions, C++11 means C++ with standart approved in 2011. I'm not sure that you need new features from C++11 version. Most of code examples from Internet use simple C++, so just delete `std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(1));` and `#include <thread>`, and you wouldn't need to use `-std=c++11`. I would be happy to give you other guides, but I don't work with `glfw` library...